# clang-modernize, unknown command line argument --remove-change-desc-files

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang

I'm using clang-modernize tool on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
clang-modernize-3.5 -include=src -p=.
```

I get the following error:

```
  clang-modernize: Unknown command line argument '--remove-change-desc-files'.
  Try: '/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/clang-modernize -help'
```

However, I don't use such an argument. Maybe it is added automatically?

Comment: I have this problem too! Would really like a solution.

Comment: I filed this bug report last summer:
http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20488
(but nothing seems to happen to fix it or find a workaround)